# How can I create a custom HTMLHelper extension that handles an item with an index

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my MVC4 website, I have a page where I'm looping through a list of items that are part of my model and putting them in a table.

My model is named JobModel and it has a list of TaskModel objects accessible in a property named Tasks.

I'm using syntax like this for each item in the list...

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Tasks[i].TaskName)
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Tasks[i].TaskName)
```

This works fine.

However, I have a need to create a Custom DisplayFor extension, that I'll name DisplayFor2 for this discussion.

My code looks like this...

```
public static IHtmlString DisplayFor2<TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TaskModel> html, Expression<Func<TaskModel, TProperty>> ex) {
   //Build my custom html here...
}
```

When I attempt this code,

```
@Html.DisplayFor2(m => m.Tasks[i].TaskName)
```

I get the compiler complaining that:

```
The type arguments for method 'IHtmlString MySite.HtmlHelpers.HelperExtensions.DisplayFor2<TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TaskModel>, Expression<Func<TaskModel,TProperty>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

What do I need to do?

****UPDATE****

I changed my method to this, and now it works.

```
public static IHtmlString TableCellFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> ex)
```

But when I do this, I don't know the index of the child item, so it's proven useless.

Comment: why don't you return `string` from your method ?

Comment: The actual method isn't DisplayFor2, I just named it that for this.  It actually creates custom HTML that contains a span tag as well as a Textbox that is hidden and a label that is not. I use jQuery to toggle the visibility of each.

Comment: You are using the wrong model type in your help. Change `TaskModel` to `JobModel` so it should look like `public static IHtmlString DisplayFor2<TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<JobModel> html, Expression<Func<JobModel, TProperty>> ex) {
   //Build my custom html here...
}` or you can go full generic: `public static IHtmlString DisplayFor2<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> ex) {
   //Build my custom html here...
}`

Comment: I changed it to this. public static IHtmlString TableCellFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> ex).  So, now this works, but I need to build the HTML for the child Task, not the Job.  I'm assuming that I'll have access to the JobModel and all it's children Tasks, but I don't know which one.  I'm going to give up on this approach. I can't seem to figure out how MVC does it.

Comment: Why do you need to index in your `TableCellFor`? Can you maybe post what are you trying to achieve in the helper?

Comment: I needed it for the name of the input control I was building in my helper method. I ended up using the TextBoxFor in the code, which works.  Now it is working, although it's not how I had originally envisioned.  Now I just need to figure out how to add the class attribute.